# Apache: how to config ip address without SeverName?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ip, passenger, ubuntu-11.04

I want to set my own sever to run my ruby on rails project(with passenger plugin). I use Apache2 on Ubuntu11.04(sever version).

It's my first time to use Apache and I have read some documents.

All the docs ask me to set SeverName,such as [Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html) and [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Preparing_for_your_first_rails_app).

Unfortunately, I don't have a domain name, can I just set IP address and use IP address to access this sever?
If it's ok, how should I do?

It's the config sample given by passenger:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yourhost.com
   DocumentRoot /somewhere/public
   <Directory /somewhere/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a net work server for access on a LAN only or are you trying to get to it from the internet? If you're only going to have one site/application on the server, you won't need to do name based virtual hosting, and serving the app from the IP address will be easy. However, if other sites/applications will be served from the server, it will be more difficult to get the server to recognize that the IP address is only for that application.

In the end though, whether you're using it only on a LAN or using it on the internet, setting a ServerName is a lot easier. Domain registration is cheap.

Comment: I want to use it on the Internet....
Is there any solution to use IP address on the Internet?
Anyway,thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the line:

```
# NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment out any `<VirtualHost>` blocks.

Find the line:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" # or whatever your config uses for the overall apache document root.
```

Change it to your rails application's root.

```
DocumentRoot "/somewhere/public"
```

Then add your other config settings to a `<Directory>` block.

```
<Directory /somewhere/public>
  AllowOverride all
  Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

I haven't tested this for sure, but you should be able to get to it by only visiting the IP address. Make sure you have Passenger installed, have run `passenger-install-apache2-module`, and have added the appropriate module loading lines to your apache config.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
          ServerName example.com
          DocumentRoot /home/urpc-name/RailsApps/anything/public
          <Directory /home/webonise/RailsApps/anything/public>
             RailsEnv development
             AllowOverride all
             Options -MultiViews
          </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

1. In server name:select ur virtual name...u can choose anything
2. In document root and directory,give your rails project path
3. Select rails environment in RailsEnv

/etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 example.com

1. Put server name in virtual host-127.0.0.1 is the localhost

---

- Then just go to your browser and type example.com

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your advice!
However, I think it can just work on local machine, right?
I want to let it be accessible on the Internet.
Any suggestion?